# How to connect distributed Go apps?

Tags: go, distributed

I have two go apps running on different machines.
I want them to communicate with each other in a native fast manner.

How do I do it better? I worked with Erlang and find very handy the way it's implemented there.

What are preferred ways to communicate between Go apps?

Comment: You could use a queue like RabbitMQ. Google also released a project called [gRPC](http://www.grpc.io/docs/guides/) which you might like.

Comment: ["net/rpc"](https://golang.org/pkg/net/rpc/), ["net/rpc/jsonrpc"](https://golang.org/pkg/net/rpc/jsonrpc/), [gRPC](http://www.grpc.io/docs/guides/), plain HTTP, asynchronously via message queue, take your pick.

Comment: You can create simple api for speaking between your apps.

Answer (score 1):

**net/rpc** - out of the box & fast

**gRPC** - fast and universal (imo the way to go)

**net/rpc/jsonrpc** - good when you need human readable messages or want to integrate 
go with client side js code

**plain HTTP** - overkill for communication between go programs, you'll have to plan routes and data encoding yourself, which is unnecessary effort

**message queue** - a bit slower approach, but you can benefit from advanced routing and persistence which they provide